# Nomenclature question: set of sets that is complete with respect to inclusion or intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for the proper nomenclature (if any) for a set of sets $\mathcal{S}$ with the property that if $S \in \mathcal{S}$ then so is any $S' \subset S$. Likewise, what is the name (if any) of such a set of sets if it is closed under intersection, i.e. if $S,S' \in \mathcal{S}$ so is $S \cap S'$.

Comment: I would just call $S$ a family of sets closed under inclusion.

Comment: Besides what @Don Thousand said, you could also say it's a hereditary collection of sets, although for a non-professional level audience I think "closed under inclusion" would be better. An [*ideal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(set_theory)) (of sets) is a nonempty collection of sets that is closed under inclusion and finite intersections, so you're considering a slight generalization of an ideal. In some work I did in the 1990s (mostly unpublished thus far, although it's been circulated a little and thus cited a few times) I had need of this concept and used the term *semi-ideal*.

Comment: Thanks both.  I'm definitely also happy with the compact verbal description suggestion, but wanted to make sure I hadn't missed a common name.

Comment: *nonempty collection of sets that is closed under inclusion and finite intersections* --- This should have been "finite unions". Also, now that I think about it some more, "closed under inclusion" might be ambiguous to some readers, with some readers wondering whether this means left-closure under the operation $\subseteq$ or right-closure under the operation $\subseteq.$ Perhaps ["closed under subsets"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22closed+under+subsets%22) is better than "closed under inclusion". However, none of these (inclusion, subsets, hereditary) is really all that problematic.